# List of variables in CMake

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to have a list of *variables* in CMake?
Specifically, what I want to do is call an existing function that takes multiple variables and checks whether they evaluate to *true*.

In some cases, some of those variables will be empty lists (which evaluate to *false*) and the function fails (as intended). But sometimes I don't even need these variables, so it would be fine if they are empty and the function should not fail due to that. Is there a way to pass some variables only in some instances?

The code I currently deal with is a CMake module to find a package:

```
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

# create empty list
list(APPEND mylib_LIBRARIES "")

# in some cases, the list contains elements
if(A)
    list(APPEND mylib_LIBRARIES "foo")
endif(A)

# if the list mylib_LIBRARIES is empty, this will fail
find_package_handle_standard_args(mylib REQUIRED_VARS bar mylib_LIBRARIES)
```

If **`A`** evaluates to true, `${mylib_LIBRARIES}` does contain content and everything is fine. Otherwise, the list is empty which evaluates to *false* internally and the last line gives an error.

Ideally, there would be a way to create a meta-variable that holds a list of variables that I want to pass to the function. Then, I could add `mylib_LIBRARIES` only in certain cases.

Pseudo code:

```
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

# create empty list
list(APPEND mylib_LIBRARIES "")

# the bar variable is always used
meta_list(APPEND METALIST bar)

# in some cases add the used variable mylib_LIBRARIES to the METALIST
if(A)
    list(APPEND mylib_LIBRARIES "foo")
    meta_list(APPEND METALIST mylib_LIBRARIES)
endif(A)

# METALIST will contain exactly the variables that need evaluation
find_package_handle_standard_args(mylib REQUIRED_VARS ${METALIST})
```

---

Note: having multiple calls to `find_package_handle_standard_args` is not practical due to combinatorical explosion.

Comment: Your approach with `METALIST` variable is correct and does exactly what you want. Does it mean, that your problem is solved? BTW, if it is acceptible for `mylib_LIBRARIES` variable to have *any* value, why you use it in `find_package_handle_standard_args()` call?

Comment: The problem is, that `METALIST` is just some pseudo-code I came up with in my head. Or are you saying that this is actually a thing? If so, I don't know the exact syntax (and would appreciate an answer with that).

Comment: mylib_LIBRARIES *must* have a value in case `A==true` (which needs to be verified later on) but it can not have a value in case `A==false`. So sometimes it is a REQUIRED_VAR and sometimes not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your pseudo code with `METALIST` variable becomes worked after simple replacement `meta_list` with `list` command. Also, you can delimit `A`-related variables ("foo") from other ones ("bar").

BTW, it is better to initialize list-variables using `set()`. This would protect from accidental collision with names in outer scope.

```
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

# List of variables dependent from 'A' condition.
set(A_VARS "")

if(A)
    set(mylib_LIBRARIES "foo") # Other libraries can be added via list()
    list(APPEND A_VARS mylib_LIBRARIES)
endif(A)

find_package_handle_standard_args(mylib REQUIRED_VARS bar ${A_VARS})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I must have gotten the syntax somehow wrong in my tries and thought it was impossible that way. Nice to be wrong sometimes.